# MongoDB and Complex Array Search

Tags: .net-4.0, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I've some 37K documents stored in Mongo that looks similar to these:

```
{
    "_id" : GUID,
    "Country" : "Germany",
    "TypeIds" : [47]
}


{
    "_id" : GUID,
    "Country" : "France",
    "TypeIds" : [54, 47]
}
```

Using the MongoDB C# driver, and based on the two example records, how can I query for the following information:

1. All documents that have TypeIds containing 47 or 54 - should result in 2 records
2. All documents that have TypeIds containing 47 AND 54 - should result in 1 records
3. All documents that have TypeIds containing 54 AND a Country of 'Germany' - should result in 0 records

Thanks,
Kieron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have class like this(i just instead of guid use GuidId.ToString()):

```
public class Test
        {

            public Test()
            {
                TypeIds = new List<int>();
            }

            [BsonId]
            public string Id { get; set; }

            public string Country { get; set; }

            public List<int> TypeIds { get; set; }
        }
```

i've inserted rows into db according above documents

```
  var collection = db.Database.GetCollection("items");
            var id1 = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            var id2 = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            var test = new Test() { Id = id1, Country = "Germany" };
            test.TypeIds.Add(47);
            var test2 = new Test() { Id = id2, Country = "France" };
            test2.TypeIds.Add(54);
            test2.TypeIds.Add(47);
            collection.Insert(test);
            collection.Insert(test2);
```

Queries:

```
//All documents that have TypeIds containing 47 or 54 - should result in 2 records
        var array = new List<int>() { 47, 54 };
        var condition1 = collection.FindAs<Test>(Query.In("TypeIds", BsonArray.Create(array))).ToList();

        //All documents that have TypeIds containing 54 AND a Country of 'Germany' - should result in 0 records
        var condition3 = collection.FindAs<Test>(Query.And(Query.EQ("TypeIds", 47), Query.EQ("Country", "Germany"))).ToList();
```

**Update**:
I found way to do second condition:

```
//All documents that have TypeIds containing 47 AND 54 - should result in 1 records

     var array2 = new List<int>() { 47, 54 };
     var query = Query.All("TypeIds",BsonArray.Create(array2));

     var condition2 = collection.FindAs<Test>(query).ToList();
```

Comment: @Kieron: sure but i actually don't know how to do second condition. In mongo syntax should be something like this {"TypeIds":47,"TypeIds":54}(you can check it in mongovue at find window). But for some reason it's not work through the c# driver. But in any way you can try ;)

Comment: Can't get to mongovue.com at the moment, it seems to be down. So is this a problem with the C# driver and MongoDB does support that query, or does MongoDB simply not support that type of query?

Comment: @Kieron:Mongovue site not working for me also. I am sure that mongodb support such quries and i think that with driver also all okay, just need to play sometime with it. I do it later, because i working now.